# jQuery DataTables <tbody> not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm new to jQuery DataTables api, and I added a row to my table using the jQuery Datatables API.  However, why doesn't the  section show up?  What do I need to do to get it to show up per row that I add to the table?

Thanks for your help!

```
<table width='200px' style="table-layout: fixed" id="downlink-table-nameserver" border>
  <thead>
    <td>Server Port WWN</td>
    <td>Server Node Name</td>
    <td>Server Port Name</td>
    <td>Server Node Name</td>             
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="connection-state"> Connection State </label>
        <div id="connection-state"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#example').dataTable();

    var serverPortWwnTitle = 'Server Port WWN',
    serverNodeWwnTitle = 'Server Node WWN',
    serverPortNameTitle = 'Server Port Name',
    serverNodeNameTitle = 'Server Node Name';     

    var linkOptions = {
        "bPaginate" : false,
        "bFilter" : false,
        "bInfo" : false,
        "bAutoWidth" : false,
        "aaData" : [],
        "aaSorting": [[ 1, "alphanumeric-asc" ]],
        "aoColumns" : [
            {
                "sTitle" : serverPortWwnTitle,
                "sWidth" : "230px",
                "mDataProp" : "serverPortWwn",
                "sType" : "string"
            }, {
                "sTitle" : serverNodeWwnTitle,
                "sWidth" : "230px",
                "mDataProp" : "serverNodeWwn",
                "sType" : "string"
            }, {                        
                "sTitle" : serverPortNameTitle,
                "sWidth" : "230px",
                "mDataProp" : "serverPortName",
                "sType" : "string"
            }, {
                "sTitle" : serverNodeNameTitle,
                "sWidth" : "230px",
                "mDataProp" : "serverNodeName",
                "sType" : "string"
            }                        
        ]
    };


    var nameSvrTable = $('#downlink-table-nameserver').dataTable(linkOptions);  

    var connMapInfo = [];             

    connMapInfo.push({
        serverPortWwn: "portwwn",
        serverNodeWwn : "nodewwn",
        serverPortName: "portname",
        serverNodeName: "nodename"
    });                               

    nameSvrTable.fnClearTable();                        
    nameSvrTable.fnAddData(connMapInfo);                               


} );
```

Answer (score 0):

First try using a correct HTML markup. Add `<tr>` to `<thead>` section, then use `<th>` instead of `<td>` inside of `<thead>`. Also, the number of cells in `<thead>` and `<tbody>` sections should match, or use `colspan="4"` to fix the current markup issue.

```
<table width='200px' style="table-layout: fixed" id="downlink-table-nameserver" border>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Server Port WWN</th>
        <th>Server Node Name</th>
        <th>Server Port Name</th>
        <th>Server Node Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <label for="connection-state"> Connection State </label>
            <div id="connection-state"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This will be a good start in solving the problem.